# Disabling `@tf.function` decorators for debugging?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

In TensorFlow 2, the [`@tf.function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/eager/tf_function) decorator allows for Python functions to become TensorFlow graphs (more or less) and can lead to some performance improvements. However, when decorated this way, [Python no longer traces the functions each time they run](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/eager/tf_function#tracing_and_polymorphism). This makes debugging the functions with Python debuggers a bit more difficult. Is there a way to disable all `@tf.function` decorators temporarily to allow for easy debugging?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/run_functions_eagerly).

Comment: In TF 2.3 and higher, this is replaced by `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)`

Answer (score 4):

You could use a global boolean variable `DEBUG` and apply it to the `autograph` argument in `@tf.function` like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
DEBUG = False

@tf.function(autograph=not DEBUG)
def foo(x):
    return x + 1
```

Otherwise, since it is `autograph=True` by default, not sure whether it is possible without modification of source code.

Comment: not recommended, if u happen to use some func like `tf.range` in `foo`, you might get error: ```OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph is disabled in this function. ```